# How to get html element runtime code to make generic copies? Like copy textbox with text entered into it

Tags: javascript, html, copy

I want to be able to copy elements with keeping everything that user entered, modified and etc.
I don't want to parse every elem like *manually set value for textboxes*, *manually set checked for radiobuttons* and etc, I need some generic way.

Is this possible?

This is what I have as example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>asd</title>

        <script type = "text/javascript">
            function copyElement(elem_id, to_elem_id)
            {
                var elem = document.getElementById(elem_id);
                var container = document.getElementById(to_elem_id);

                if (!elem || !container)
                    return;

                container.innerHTML = elem.outerHTML;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type = "text" id = "test_txt" />
        <input type = "button" value = "copy textbox" onclick = "copyElement('test_txt', 'for_elem_paste')" />
        <span id = 'for_elem_paste'></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want that copied textbox to appear with text entered in original textbox.
But this not about textboxes, I need to copy any elements. I though that `innerHTML` and `outerHTML` keep things that modified by user :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone it

```
function copyElement(elem_id, to_elem_id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elem_id);
    var container = document.getElementById(to_elem_id);
    if (elem && container) {
        var clone = elem.cloneNode(true);
        clone.id = "some other id to prevent id duplication";
        container.appendChild(clone);
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Ugh... is there anyway to get it's html code with entered things? Actually, I planning to store that code in some array, so later, I can assign that code to some container.innerHTML, so user will not lose what he entered or modified. More than that, I want to save that code to file, so another user later can open it and see what first user entered.